# Selecting lists within a list that are of a certain length

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

This is what I have:

`original_list=[[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3]]`

I would like to find lists within my list that are of lengths 2, 3, 4, etc.:

`length2_list=[[1,2],[1,2]]`

`length3_list=[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`

`length4_list=[[1,2,3,4]]`

How might I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

list comprehensions

```
#don't call lists "list" as a variable 
l=[[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3]]

#for len 2
l_2=[x for x in l if len(x)==2]

#for len 3
l_3=[x for x in l if len(x)==3]
```

etc

Comment: You should try running your code before you post it as a solution. It should be `==` and not `=`.

Comment: @Bazingaa yes how sloppy of me. fixed

Answer (score 1):

It's simple with Len() function which can tell you the lengths of list

```
origal_list=[[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3]]

length2_list=[]

length3_list=[]

length4_list=[]


for lst in origal_list:
    if len(lst) == 2:
        length2_list.append(lst)
    if len(lst) == 3:
        length3_list.append(lst)
    if len(lst) == 4:
        length4_list.append(lst)

print(length2_list)
print(length3_list)
print(length4_list)
```

result:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, it will work for n lists of n length:

```
lists = {}
list = [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]]

for l in list:
    length = len(l)
    if lists.get(length) is None:
        lists[length] = []
    lists[length].append(l)
```

This creates a dictionary that will have the length as the key for a list of lists. It then iterates over the original list and appends it to the correct key.

It will output something like this: `{2: [[1, 2], [1, 2]], 3: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], 4: [[1, 2, 3, 4]]}`